# Why is this particular solution giving extraneous roots (solving $z^n= \bar z$)

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

[image]

I can't understand why this is giving extraneous roots. The real set of solutions is supposed to be fourth roots of unity.

Comment: This just says that if the first equation is satisfied then so is the second, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If $z \neq 0$ and $z^3= \bar{z}$ then $|z| = 1$ and so $z^3 = \bar{z} $**iff** $z^4 = 1$.
Hence you are looking for the fourth roots of one.

If $z^4 = 1$ then $z^{8} = 1$, but not the other way around, because the map $w \mapsto w^2$ is not injective.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring, cubing, or doing other such operations to both sides of an equation often introduces extraneous roots. Observe, for instance:

\begin{align*}
x+1 = -2 
&\implies (x+1)^2 = (-2)^2 \\
&\implies (x+1)^2 = 4 \tag{$\ast$}\\
&\implies |x+1| = 2 \\
&\implies x \in \left\{ -1+2, -1-2 \right\} = \left\{ 1,-3 \right\}
\end{align*}

We start with the equation $x+1=-2$, and square both sides. After simplifying, note at $(\ast)$ in particular that what we have is a second-degree equation, a quadratic, which has two distinct solutions most of the time.

From there, we take the square root, and note that $\sqrt{z^2} = |z|$. From there, we can solve for $x$, and indeed have two solutions.

The reason this arises is that squaring both sides is not a bijective operation -- you cannot always "undo" it cleanly, so squaring both sides, in a sense, causes you to lose information.

The same is true for any integer power you raise both sides to, because you can be introducing a bunch of extraneous solutions. Say you have a degree $d$ polynomial set equal to something else, and then raise both sides to the $n$th power; you could have as many as $n \cdot d$ solutions to the resulting equation, because the polynomial is now one of degree $n \cdot d$.

This is also why I wrote my derivation above using forward implications and not $\iff$ ("if and only if") arrows, because it's not undoable.

Your situation - or at least the issue you have with your method of solution - is very analogous to that I mentioned with my much-simpler problem.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you also get the solutions to $\bar{z}^3=-z$, because cubing and taking complex conjugate of this equation would also give
$$
z^9=\overline{(\bar{z}^3)^3}=\overline{(-z)^3}=-\bar{z}^3=-(-z)=z.
$$